# Install OpenCV for Python and Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, opencv

I am trying to install OpenCV 4.0 in my Kubuntu 18.10 machine. I have done

```
sudo cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE \
           -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local \
           -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON \
           -D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=OFF \
           -D OPENCV_ENABLE_NONFREE=ON \
           -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=~/util/opencv_contrib/modules \
           -D PYTHON_EXECUTABLE=/usr/bin/python \
           -D PYTHON3_EXECUTABLE=/usr/bin/python3 \
           -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON ..

sudo make -j12
sudo make install
sudo ldconfig
```

and all goes smooth. However, when I import, I get

```
ImportError: No module named cv2
```

for both python and python3. File are located in

```
/usr/local/python/cv2/python-2.7/cv2.so
/usr/local/python/cv2/python-3.6/cv2.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
```

but not in

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/
```

and 3.6 does not even have a "site-packages" directory. I have been trying to symlink, but with no success. I do not want to install them in a virtualenv.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: I ended up linking the cv2.so files to my ./local/lib/python2.7<3.6>/sites-packages, now it works.